# Formatação de tipos float

Tags: python, float, conversão

Pesquisei um pouco antes de perguntar, sabem dizer por que não mostra 2.500 na saída, e sim 2.5

```
salario=float(input("Digite seu salario"))

print(salario)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Porque 2.5 é igual a 2.500**, basta fazer o teste:

```
print(2.5 == 2.500)
```

Irá retornar `True`

O ponto é usado como separado do *"ponto flutuante"*, aliais é por isto mesmo que se chama *"ponto flutuante"*, então os zeros a direita são suprimidos, o mesmo ocorre com calculadoras.

Agora se o teu objetivo é usar `,` como separador e pontos como separadores de milhar a a história é outra, teria que usar `replace`, por exemplo:

```
x = '2.500,01'
x = x.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')
x = float(x)
print(x)
```

Se tiver `R$` na string passada use:

```
x = 'R$ 2.500,01'

x = x.replace('R$', '') # remove o R$
x = x.strip()           # remove espaços em branco
x = x.replace('.', '')  # remove os pontos
x = x.replace(',', '.') # troca  virgula do decimal por ponto

x = float(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: No meu caso era pra por o valor R$ 2.500,00.

Comment: @AndréSilva então usa o segundo exemplo que postei, entenda uma coisa, numero é numero, string é string, isso para o computador não é um numero "2.500,00" é uma string, com o replace da forma que mostrei você converte para numero.

Comment: Entendi cara muito obrigado pelas dicas, vou tentar!